# Is an SSL certificate verification by thumbprint and serialnumber secure enough?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, man-in-the-middle

I need to validate a few SSL certificates(`X509Certificate2`) in my app and I was wondering if a decent approach could be by only comparing the `X509Certificate2.Thumbprint` and `X509Certificate2.SerialNumber` of the certificate since both should be unique (aside from possible collision of the hash algorithm).

What are the attacking vectors with this approach? I know that a proper validation includes several steps (chain validation, CRL, etc) but if I only have to validate a specific amount of certificates and not "all possible" certificates, this approach looks quite good (comparing to the work I have to put it)

Comment: Maybe this is a question for http://security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: The serial number is not unique and can be set by a possible attacker

Comment: With that approach, you can't revoke a certificate if needed.

Comment: ok but a possible attacker cannot the the thumbprint right? And I can revoke a certificate from the client side by updating the app and from a server side I just could change the certificate right?